# copy files from one folder and paste them to another location under same folder name

Tags: backup, directory, scripts, rename

Please, I need help with backup...
I am trying to do something and I have NO IDEA how to start.
I want to make a script in Ubuntu that would search through all folders of my W7 partition, and wherever there are .cdr files it would ( select and ) copy all files from that folder ( .jpg, .png, .pdf, ...) but not other folders in that folder. Then it would paste those files onto my external drive in folder named exactly as the one those files were copied from.

I KNOW IT'S complicated, and my English is not very good.

I hope you can understand what I am struggling with and help me.

Any help or even advice is very much appreciated. THANK YOU !

Answer (score 2):

### Script

Not too terrible with some `find`, `rsync` and bash script magic. Put this into a file (`backup.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

source_dir=${1:-<source directory>}
dest_dir=${2:-<destination directory>}
tmp_file=/tmp/$USER/bkp_files

find "$source_dir" -name '*.cdr' -print | while read file; do
    find "$(dirname $file)" -maxdepth 1 -xtype f -print
    done > "$tmp_file"

rsync --files-from "$tmp_file" / "$dest_dir"
```

Then you have to make it executable with

```
$ chmod +x backup.sh
```

And you can run the script with

```
$ ./backup.sh
```

### Step by step

Let me explain

```
find "$source_dir" -name '*.cdr' -print
```

finds all the .cdr files in `$source_dir`
This is then piped into a while loop:

```
| while read file; do ...  done > "$tmp_file"
```

This takes every file from the previous `find` command, executes some commands and writes the result to `$tmp_file`. Note: This only works if the filename don't contain newlines, which should be given with a windows partition. The second find is

```
find "$(dirname $file)" -maxdepth 1 -xtype f -print
```

Here `$(dirname $file)` gives us the directory name of the .cdr file. It is the start point for our next find command. There we don't descend into subdirs with `-maxdepth 1` and are only interested in files `-xtype f`

Lastly we use rsync to copy the files we saved in `$tmp_file`:

```
rsync --files-from "$tmp_file" / "$dest_dir"
```

`rsync` will keep the directory tree structure as is, which is what you want, right?

For more infos see the man pages:

```
$ man find
$ man rsync
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! 
but can I use it the same way to manage files between two USB drives ?

Comment: Sure, just change the `source_dir` and ``dest_dir` or pass them to the script.